# Шифрование и безопасность в менеджере паролей

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность, шифрование, пароль

Вопрос, касающийся сторон безопасности в разработке менеджера паролей.

### **1. Вводная.**

Для общего развития я работаю над реализацией менеджера паролей, стек react + node.js + mongodb. Есть тачка (digitalocean), развёрнуты два приложения - клиент и бекенд, оба на своих поддоменах с прикрученным https (с помощью certbot с автопродлением). На входе в ip сервера поднят общий прокси на ноде с маршрутизацией по поддоменам (вдруг это важно).

Теперь вопрос к ops'ерам: может ли подобный способ развёртки как-либо сказаться на безопасности, масштабируемости и пропускной способности (менее десятка тысяч юзеров)?

### **2. Схема обмена ключами и их генерация.**

[image: Аутентификация]

1. Клиент проходит аутентификацию, передает пароль по https в теле post-запроса.
2. Бекенд, владея своим общим для всех юзеров ключом, генерирует общий ключ для клиента на основе своего ключа и пароля юзера в качестве второй части.
3. Бекенд возвращает http-only secured куку заголовком Set-Cookie, внутри сгенерированный общий ключ для текущего юзера.

**Итого:** сервер не сможет расшифровать данные юзера без участия этого юзера. Но если его пароль утечёт, то данные будут расшифрованы третьим лицом. В таком случае можно использовать не пароль, а кодовую фразу (passcode), которая применятеся самим юзером для блокировки сессии без логаута, что-то вроде дополнительного пароля. Такая практика обычно используется другими менеджерами паролей.

[image: Запрос]

1. В каждом запросе клиент будет передавать куку с общим ключом бекенду.
2. Бекенд в свою очередь будет в каждом запросе проверять ключ на наличие и валидность.
3. Если что-то идёт не так, бекенд чистит куку заголовком Set-Cookie с просроченной датой жизни и возвращает 401 статус.
4. Если клиент получает 401 ошибку, то отображает форму ввода кодовой фразы (passcode) для повторной генерации ключа бекендом. Разлогина при этом нет, сессия продолжается.

### **3. Теперь главные вопросы по шифрованию и безопасности.**

**1. Адекватен ли общий flow по шифрованию и обмену между веб-клиентом и бекендом?**

**2. Безопасно ли держать ключ в http-only куке?**
Полагаю, что да, раз к ней не будет доступа в js.

**3. Какой способ шифрования требуется в данной ситуации?**
Вероятно, это должно быть симметричное шифрование типа AES, только ключ для шифровки/расшифровки должен быть сгенерирован из двух половинок - passcode юзера и общего ключа бекенда. И в целом, какие виды шифрования сейчас считаются наиболее безопасными и современными?

**4. Реализуется ли это всё адекватно на js?**
Судя по всему, мне нужно средство генерации ключа и средство для самого шифрования. Было бы здорово увидеть сразу ссылки на либы ну или просто названия алгоритмов/методов/видов.

**5. Как хранить данные в бд?**
Пароли юзеров, которые используются при аутентификации и авторизации, я шифрую с помощью bcrypt. Сервер не может их расшифровать, только сравнить. Все остальные данные, видимо, должны быть в виде хеша после шифровки, если я всё правильно понимаю.

---

Главный вопрос, конечно, пункт 3 - конкретные решения/алгоритмы/методы/виды шифрования в моём случае.

Comment: я не спец по шифрованию, но вы можете хешировать пароль для аутентификации, но вы не можете хешировать данные, что вам надо будет восстановить - это только шифровать / дешифровать.

Comment: @tym32167, да, вы правы, хотя в данном случае это не существенно. Главное понять, какое решение подходит для реализации, я не силен в этих сотнях видов шифрования.

Comment: по поводу (3) я бы использовал ассиметричное шифрование, мне это кажется более надежным. Тогда можно один ключт у юзера хранить, второй на сервере. Или пусть юзер шифрует открытым ключем, и засылает на сервер. Или 2 пры ключей иметь. Хотя так можно и HTTPS переизобрести :)

Comment: @tym32167, в точку! как бы не создать что-то мегаперегруженное. Здесь роль ключа пользователя выполняет его пароль (passcode), и завести еще один ключ каждому и хранить его на клиентах будет оверхэдом, если я правильно мыслю. Тут должно быть что-то проще, чем по две пары ключей фактически на каждого пользователя.

Comment: я бы не завязывался на пароль, а то вдруг юзер его забует и все, приехали.